# NGRX multiple subscription issue with Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, ngrx

I am using ionic 4 with ngrx. I have a user selector on Page A and Page b both.

```
export class ComponentA implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  private readonly ngUnsubscribe: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();
  user:any;
  constructor(
    private readonly store: Store<AppState>,
  ) { }

ngOnInit(){}

  ionViewWillEnter(): void {
    this.store.select(getUserState)
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe))
      .subscribe((user) => {
        this.user = user;
      });
  }

  ionViewWillLeave(): void {
    this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
    this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
    getUserState.release();
  }
```

Same subscriptions on page b , when i move from page a to b unsubscribe works but then when i move from b to a and then a to b .. subscription on page a doesn't get unsubscribe. If you traverse back 5 times 5 subscription remains on page a.Both pages get notification. I know in ionic previous page remains in stack so onDestroy() never gets called on forward navigation that is why i have put in subscription and unsubscription in ionic lifecyle hooks.
Please suggest how to fix this . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that after the very first leave `this.ngUnsubscribe` is completed, that means next time when `ionViewWillLeave` is called `this.ngUnsubscribe` is completed and won't emit the termination signal.

You can move the complete part to the ngOnDestroy to keep the stream active until real dispose.

```js
export class ComponentA implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  private readonly ngUnsubscribe: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();
  user:any;
  constructor(
    private readonly store: Store<AppState>,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(){}

  ionViewWillEnter(): void {
    this.store.select(getUserState)
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe))
      .subscribe((user) => {
        this.user = user;
      });
  }

  ionViewWillLeave(): void {
    this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
    getUserState.release();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
  }
}
```